# Labelling Subgroups in a String variable (Stata)

Tags: stata

I am trying to label subgroups within a string categorical variable:
I have a sex variable stored in "double" format and to make it easier to use in graphs, I converted the variable into string as below

```
tostring sex, gen(sex_str)
```

And then I wanted to label the groups following instructions [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/modules/labeling-data/), and it worked:

```
label define sex_strlabel 1 "Male" 2 "Female"
```

However, when I ran the code below I got this error message "may not label strings"

```
label values sex_strsex_strlabel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need `sex` in a string format, I would do it like this:

```
clear

input double sex
1
2
end

label define x1 1"Male" 2"Female"
label value sex x1

decode sex, gen(sex_string)
```

Comment: That's very good advice. Even better would be to recommend a (0, 1) indicator variable named for the state coded 1, e.g. 0 male 1 female for `female`. More at https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099